# How can I pass a function with 2 parameters as a parameter to a function?

Tags: rust

I have the following:

```
fn apply_bin(&mut self, op: Fn(i32,i32)) -> Result<i32, String> {

}
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
<anon>:75:29: 75:31 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `core::ops::Fn(i32, i32) + 'static` [E0277]
<anon>:75     fn apply_bin(&mut self, op: Fn(i32,i32)) -> Result<i32, String> {
                                      ^~
```

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a generic method, because `Fn` is a trait:

```
fn apply_bin<F>(&mut self, op: F) -> Result<i32, String>
    where F: Fn(i32, i32)
{
}
```

(this is static dispatch)

You can also use dynamic dispatch:

```
fn apply_bin(&mut self, op: &Fn(i32, i32)) -> Result<i32, String>
{
}
```

There is more info in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/closures.html#taking-closures-as-arguments).